# passport-facebook-token returns InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile when verifying the token

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have an iOS app in which I use Facebook API for logging in, and I get an access token in response. Now I want to use this token to authenticate user on my backend server.

I'm using passport-facebook-token strategy for Passport.js.

```
 var FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');

 module.exports = function(app) {
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());

      passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
        clientID: '32424222424024',
        clientSecret: '3292e42148264c2817523232446187',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
      },

      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            console.log("facebook");
            return done(err, user);
        });
      }   
      ));

    app.get('/auth/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook-token'),
        function (req, res) {
            res.send(req.user? 200 : 401);
        }
    );
 };
```

But when I call http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook?access_token=my_token_here I get following error:

> InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
>       at C:\app\www\app\node_modules\passport-facebook-token\lib\index.js:152:32
>       at passBackControl (C:\app\www\app\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:123:9)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\app\www\app\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)

What steps in app configuration and/or authentication implementation am I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, check your ClientId and Client Secret, then check if you choose a correct app to [test](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/312514756074941) your connection to Facebook by Postman (or similar). 
In my case, the problem was with generating token to another app 
[image]